# How to update header text in hook_views_pre_render

Tags: hooks, views

I have a view with a header of type "Global: Unfiltered text" that contains the string "Number of drivers: ".

In hook_views_pre_render I count the total number of drivers in each row, and now I want to append this number to the string in my view header.

I did a print_r on the $view object in hook_views_pre_render and found 59 instances of that string.

If it was only a few I would just try replacing each one until it had the desired result - but 59?!?! Too much recursion...

So how do I find which value to update in order to update the text in my view header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the important thing is to narrow down the particular view `display` you want to affect. Then you can look at the header text later. I have the following similiar code ... you should be able to use views_pre_render fine, I don't use that here:

```
function MYMODULE_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'migration_audits') {
    $drupal_nids = array();
    if (count($view->result)) {
      foreach ($view->result as $i => $node) {
        $drupal_nids []= $node->nid;
      }
    }
   $sql = " ... ";
   $result = db_query($sql, array(':drupal_nids' => $drupal_nids));
    $output = '';
    foreach ($result as $course) {
      #dpm($course);
      $title = html_entity_decode($course->course_title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
      $instructors = html_entity_decode($course->instructor, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
      $output .= "<div class=\"entry\">$course->quarter $course->year - $title Instructors:&nbsp;$instructors</div>";
    }


    $my_values = "<style type=\"text/css\">div.legacy_values { background-color: pink;} div.legacy_values div.entry { padding-bottom: 5px; }</style><div class=\"legacy_values\">$output</div>";
    $view->display['page']->handler->handlers['header']['area_1']->options['content'] = $my_values;
    $view->display['page']->handler->handlers['header']['area_1']->options['empty'] = 0;
  }
}
```

You can also do like `$view->display[$view->current_display]` usually as a safe none hard coded approach. Note that the global header regions are given names such as `area_1`, `area_2` etc as a convention by Views. I also tell Views the area is now not empty.

Comment: I was unable to update the header value using  $view->display['page']->handler->handlers['header']['area_1']->options['content'] = $my_values; this code