# Update header in hook_views_pre_render

Tags: hooks, views

I have seen how to update a views header via hook_views_pre_render or hook_views_post_execute [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95994/how-to-update-header-text-in-hook-views-pre-render), but I am asking myself why one should go about this to update the value:

```
$view->display['page']->handler->handlers['header']['area_1']->options['content'] = $my_values;
```

While testing the same it seems to me that this is also working:

```
$view->header['area_1']->options['content']` = $my_values;
```

Is there any reason why I should/could not use this shorter code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The longer line would be helpful if you wanted to target only one display. For instance if there were a page display and block display and were both overriding the "master" and you only wanted to override the page display then the first line would be the way to go.

If the master display is what you want to override the second option is clearer.

FWIW, it might be better to simply have multiple displays that alternate whatever you're switching between in this hook. While quick, implementations of hooks like these are hard for a team to maintain over time.

Comment: Ok, so the short line is targeting the master display. I know it is better to have different displays and I am always trying to do like this, but here I am tried to do something that I could not solve via Views UI.