# Unable to update header value using hook_views_pre_render?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I have create the header value using Global: Unfiltered text (Global: Unfiltered text) .

BY us hook_views_pre_render i want to update the header value . How can I update the header value .

[How to update header text in hook_views_pre_render](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95994/how-to-update-header-text-in-hook-views-pre-render) provide the solution for the header value to update but its not working for me

```
    function mytheme_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {

      if ($view->id() == 'works') {
//    enter code here
             $my_value='No result found';
             $view->display['page']->handler->handlers['header']
             ['area_1']->options['content'] = $my_values;

        }   

      }
    }
```

Comment: Why do this via a hook at all? Views has an option to configure the no results text built in.

Comment: "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR" is used to static message show . But I want to show the dynamic value which will get from url.

Comment: dynamic value not using if result is empty.

Comment: Best way is to create your own custom views area handler in that case, rather than use that hook. This article seems the most relevant: https://www.aram.cz/article/creating-custom-views-header-handler-drupal-7 - I don't have time right now to turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $view->display['page']->handler->handlers['header']
             ['area_1']->options['content'] = $my_values;
```

please change the value of the area_1 if anyone want change the header value programmatically .

Just hover the **Global: Unfiltered text (Global: Unfiltered text)** header value and you will get the area_1 value .